# In spring boot project the web page work only once at time

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

In spring boot project the web page work only one time when i tried another time it show

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Tue Jul 27 09:12:40 IST 2021
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
```

Comment: Look into your logfiles to see what error you get.

Answer (score 0):

This means that your request has actually reached the web endpoint that was defined in the application, but then it has crushed while processing the request.

The exception has been thrown and probably you'll be able to see it in the logs of your application.
Spring tries to handle it gracefully, but probably this is an exception that spring doesn't have an associated handler for, hence it responds with an http status "500" internal server error (or its also possible that this exception indeed requires spring to return 500 http status).

Bottom line, examine the logs for exceptions.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Of course it can :) Its your application, right? So you have an issue in the code - you should merely fix it and then it will work ;) Other than that its hard to tell what exactly happens without delving into the code, You're basically asking a very general question...